# THE Shouting sitename

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, design

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) This is intended and will remain in current shape.

---

The site name in the upper left is in capital letters **CODE REVIEW** which just isn't right. The same goes with meta.

To clarify why it isn't right

[image]

and the old one

[image]

vs the new one

[image]

Comment: it's not shouting. it's matter of styling. what you see in header is LOGO. what you see in sites dropdown is just a list with names. I personally think that the consistency between those two places in unfounded (also check out stackoverfow. it has capital letters in dropdown but no capital letters in logo). nevertheless, i think this is very objective opinion and, for sure, is not a bug. but thanks for reporting!

Comment: @Paweł WHEN USING ALL CAPS PEOPLE GET ANNOYED. I CAN SAY _"THIS IS MY PERSONAL STYLE OF WRITING TO SHOW THAT I'M SPECIAL"_, BUT IN REALITY IT IS JUST RUDE. MAKE IT A MONOSPACE FONT TO GIVE IT A SORT OF CODE-REVIEW-SPECIALIZED LAYOUT, MAYBE WITH A DOT OR LINE THROUGH THE O TO BETTER DISTINGUISH IT FROM A 0 LIKE IDE-FONTS TEND TO DO, BUT THE ALLCAPS SHOULD GO.

Comment: @nwp did you get annoyed by those two words in caps? do you feel like someone was rude for you when you saw that logo? I got annoyed by this long paragraph in caps. but not logo (two words) in caps... btw. you should really talk to few companies about their logos: Samsung, Bosch, Mitsubishi, Chase Bank, (...) and few more. I think they all crossed the line... (it's joke, don't take it as offensive)

Comment: @nwp YEAH I'M SUPER OFFENDED BY A CAPS-LOCKED LOGO. oh wait, no I'm not.

Comment: @Paweł Well you are a designer and I am not. Just saying that whatever the intend behind the allcaps was: It missed it's mark for me. But it seems everyone else is enthusiastic, so maybe I'm just weird. Also the allcaps logo isn't offensive or bad, just not as nice as it would be without the allcaps.

Answer (score 12):

I actually kinda like the new site name...

Answer (score 11):

The upper-case version of a word is still the same, it's simply styling.

Additionally, the following SE sites have the same style of '*shoutcase*' titling:

- [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)
- [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)
- [Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/)
- [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/)
- [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)
- [Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/)
- [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/)
- [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)
- [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/)
- [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)
- [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/)
- [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/)
- [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/)
- [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/)
- [Role Playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/)
- [TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)
- [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/)
- [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

So I'd say it's more than common...

Comment: Ok, I should have followed the links to understand what you mean ;-)